# /cron path found when testing site

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, owasp

I am testing a site and using `dirb` tool built into kali and it picked up `/cron` with a 200 response. I went to that page and it is blank. Can someone tell me why that was picked up and there is nothing there to view?

Answer (score 2):

Just because a webserver returns a 200, that does not mean that there has to be content there. Why this site is returning 200 and not displaying anything is not something we can tell you.

Just having a page or a directory is never a vulnerability on its own. Returning a 200 and not displaying content is not a vulnerability. But they are reasons for looking deeper.

`dirb` is part of the "recon" phase.

Answer (score 1):

It means there is a directory or page with the name `cron` on the server. From the information you've provided, that's all that can be said: it could be a blank file that someone has put there (e.g. they ran `touch cron` in the web root), or could be a page which requires some form of authentication to actually do anything (e.g. it accepts a specific GET parameter then runs some housekeeping tasks on the site).